# Access DAO Inserting whole record into Another Recordset

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to move all of the cords from one recordset to another and was wondering if a specific method could do this. Here is my code.

```
    Dim maxDate As Variant

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim destin As DAO.Recordset

maxDate = DMax("[Eff Date]", "400_CF_BREAK_LOG")
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("860_APPEND_DIFFERENCES") 'myTable is a MS-Access table created previously
Set destin = db.OpenRecordset("400_CF_BREAK_LOG")

'populate the table
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If (rs![Eff Date] > maxDate) Then
        destin.
    Debug.Print (rs!myField) 'myField is a field name in table myTable
rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

I am caught at the destin.    <---- Add the whole record here.

EDIT. The chosen answer while correct, might not account for a differing number of fields between tables. I find myself using this set-up for adding three different recordsets. Taken from [Insert Complete RecordSet to another table in other database MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31249181/insert-complete-recordset-to-another-table-in-other-database-ms-access?rq=1)

```
    maxDate = DMax("[Eff Date]", "400_CF_BREAK_LOG")
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("mytable") 'myTable is a MS-Access table created previously

'populate the table
rs.MoveFirst
Do While Not rs.EOF
    If (rs![Eff Date] > maxDate) Then
        sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO 400_CF_BREAK_LOG (Eff Date, PrimarySecurity ID Number, CUSIP(Aladdin ID), IsrName, Asset Type, Metlife Port Code, Business Unit, Principal Difference, Total PAM Principal, Total Aladdin Principal,Income Difference, Total PAM Interest,Total Aladdin Interest,Total CF Difference,Total PAM CF,PAM Coupon)" & _
        " VALUES ('" & rs("Eff Date") & "', '" & rs("PrimarySecurity ID Number") & "', '" & rs("CUSIP(Aladdin ID)") & "', '" & rs("IsrName") & "', '" & rs("Asset Type") & "', '" & rs("Metlife Port Code") & "', '" & rs("Business Unit") & "', '" & rs("Principal Difference") & "',  '" & rs("Total PAM Principal") & "',  '" & rs("Total Aladdin Principal") & "', & '" & rs("Income Difference") & "',  '" & rs("Total PAM Interest") & "',   '" & rs("Total Aladdin Interest") & "',   '" & rs("Total CF Difference") & "',    '" & rs("Total PAM CF") & "',    '" & rs("PAM Coupon") & "')"
        DoCmd.RunSQL (sqlinsert)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify this to your need (here source and target is the same table):

```
Public Sub CopyRecords()

  Dim rstSource   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rstInsert   As DAO.Recordset
  Dim fld         As DAO.Field
  Dim strSQL      As String
  Dim lngLoop     As Long
  Dim lngCount    As Long

  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblStatus WHERE Location = '" & _
                "DEFx" & "' Order by Total"

  Set rstInsert = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
  Set rstSource = rstInsert.Clone
  With rstSource
    lngCount = .RecordCount
    For lngLoop = 1 To lngCount
      With rstInsert
        .AddNew
          For Each fld In rstSource.Fields
            With fld
              If .Attributes And dbAutoIncrField Then
                ' Skip Autonumber or GUID field.
              ElseIf .Name = "Total" Then
                ' Insert default job code.
'                  datNow = Now
                rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = 0
              ElseIf .Name = "PROCESSED_IND" Then
                rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = vbNullString
              Else
                ' Copy field content.
                rstInsert.Fields(.Name).Value = .Value
              End If
            End With
          Next
          ' Insert fields not existing in source table
          rstInsert!SomeField.Value = SomeValue
          rstInsert!SomeOtherField.Value = SomeOtherValue
          rstInsert!YetAField.Value = ThirdValue
        .Update
      End With
      .MoveNext
    Next
    rstInsert.Close
    .Close
  End With

  Set rstInsert = Nothing
  Set rstSource = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I guess a follow up question is this. If I have x fields in Table 1 but x + y fields in Table 2 , would this still work. I am finding myself using a manual insert because of the disjoint in the number of fields. See edit on Question.

Comment: The whole idea is to avoid running the slow SQL _Insert .._ multiple times. One method to add values to extra fields of the target table is shown in the edited answer.